# CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert Adding web site link to text

Tags: macos, core-foundation

I have a CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert opening in my project that is just displaying text for asserts.

I want to make some of the text inside my window link to a site with information on how to fix that issue.

Is it possible to tag some of the text inside my fullText var to be a hyperlink?

I am already using all 3 buttons that you can create for other functionality so i can't use one of them to link to my sites page.

If any one has any other ideas on how to link to a page that would also be appreciated.

My code looks like:

```
// Show the window!

  CFOptionFlags responseFlags;
  CFStringRef strTitle = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "Assert Failed", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
  CFStringRef strBody = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, fullText, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
  CFStringRef strBreak = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "Break", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
  CFStringRef strIgnore = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "Ignore", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
  CFStringRef strIgnoreAll = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "Ignore All", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

  CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert (
                                 0.0f,
                                 kCFUserNotificationCautionAlertLevel,
                                 NULL, // iconURL,
                                 NULL, // soundURL,
                                 NULL, // localizationURL,
                                 strTitle,
                                 strBody,
                                 strBreak, // defaultButtonTitle,
                                 strIgnoreAll, // alternateButtonTitle,
                                 strIgnore, // otherButtonTitle,
                                 &responseFlags
                                 );
```

Comment: I think it is not possible, since the text parameters are of type `CFStringRef`, not `CFAttributedStringRef`.

Comment: Alright thanks for letting me know, I have seen other windows before with links in them but I will work on a different solution. Playing with the idea of just using the check box you can add to the window to open the link when the window is dismissed.